# Prove $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is not a domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain

If $n>1$ is not a prime number,
$\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$ is commutative ring,
where $n>1$ is a fixed natural number,
then $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is not an integral domain.

natural number is either a prime number or a product of two numbers...
integral domain is  $ac=ab$, then $b=c$ ($a$ is not $0$) its mean, zero divisor does not work in The law concellation.
If $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ has zero divisor, then this proof will be easy.
But how to prove $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ has zero divisor?

Comment: If $n$ is not prime there are $n_1$ and $n_2$ such that neither one is equal to $1$ and $n_1n_2=n$.

Comment: (For the record, this is not linear algebra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a number $n$ is the product of two numbers $a$ and $b$ where both are not equal to 1, which is possible since $n$ is not prime, then the residue classes of $a$ and $b$ are both nonzero but their product is zero mod $n$.